# Update SQL Table Based On Composite Primary Key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, etl

I have an ETL process (CSV to SQL database) that runs daily, but the data in the source sometimes changes, so I want to have it run again the next day with an updated file.

How do I write a SQL statement to find all the differences?

For example, let's say `Table_1` has a composite `PRIMARY KEY` consisting of `FK_1`,  `FK_2` and `FK_3`.

Do I do this in SQL or in the ETL process?

Thanks.

**Edit**
I realize now this question is too broad. Disregard.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking here.

Comment: Google.co.in .....

Answer (score 1):

You can use [EXCEPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql) to find which are the `IDs` which are missing. For example:

```
SELECT FK_1,  FK_2, FK_2
FROM new_data_table
EXCEPT
SELECT FK_1,  FK_2, FK_2
FROM current_data_table;
```

It will be better (in performance prospective) to materialized these IDs and then to join this new table to the `new_data_table` in order to insert all of the columns.

If you need to do this in one query, you can use simple `LEFT JOIN`. For example:

```
INSERT INTO current_data_table
SELECT A.*
FROM new_data_table A
LEFT JOIN current_data_table B
    ON A.FK_1 = B.FK_1
    AND A.FK_2 = B.FK_2
    AND A.FK_3 = B.FK_3
WHRE B.[FK_1] IS NULL;
```

The idea is to get all records in the `new_data_table` for which, there is no match in the `current_data_table` table (`WHRE B.[FK_1] IS NULL`).